Parsing a raw bytes through a string goes wrong in Java
I have problem with JTextArea, I just want to edit raw bytes (presented to String) from JTextArea, but some symbols have '?' character.
Firstly just for test, I wrote console program for test on symbol_matrix.bin:

I parsed this using String in my code, and now the file looks that:

String can't handle 0x98 and replacing it with 0x3f '?'.
Why?
I'm using this code:
import java.io.*;

public final class StringRawTest {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("symbol_matrix.bin");
        byte[] arr = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(arr);
        in.close();
        String str = new String(arr);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("symbol_matrix_output.bin");
        out.write(str.getBytes());
        out.close();
    }
}

I'll be glad you answer.

Have you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A- ?

There's no info about decoding unknown characters, and about '?'.

@BHmsgameJava Which charset do you use? You can eval it with java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().

Also There is no such thing as plain text

@BHmsgameJava what do you mean by "There's no info about decoding unknown characters"? It states "The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified." (replacing by ? can be one unspecified behavior)

It would have helped to post a link to symbol_matrix.bin

you probably can, not meaning you should, do that using the ISO_8859_1 charset: new String(arr, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); and str.getBytes(StandardCharsets,ISO_8859_1) -- but still not sure how that would work with a JTextArea and why you want to do that

g00se, I already posted as image in the question. First image.

That's not the same thing

user85421, thanks, charset decoding right in both! If you'd answered me instead comment I'd make your answer best.

Looks like your file is encoded in Windows-1251.

@g00se looking at the screenshot, that file is obviously the first 256 bytes from 0 to 255 and can easily be created with var bytes = new byte[256]; for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) bytes[i] = (byte) i; Files.write(Path.of("symbol_matrix.bin"), bytes);

As @Sören says, that's probably Windows-1251. There is one 'hole' in that at 0x98, i.e. it's undefined. It's not clear what your goal
is though. If you're making a hex editor, that's probably a tricky business ;)

Be aware there are many more holes in ISO8859-1, if you're operating on the "I want to depict a raw byte as a character" basis. Of course, which character represents which byte is somewhat subjective, nation/language-specific etc.

Anytime bytes turn into characters or vice versa, charset encoding is applied. That is simply how it is - you can't say: "Oh, okay, how do I turn that off". Because strings contain characters (not bytes), so if you say: Here are some bytes; please make it a string, that is like saying: "Here are some euros. Please pay this US company" - that's not possible, somebody is going to have to convert that to dollars.
With new String(bytes), charset encoding is applied. And whenever that happens, a charset is NECESSARILY involved.
You should use new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1) - the 2-arg constructor where you are explicit about the charset. You've used the 1-arg constructor which means you get the 'platform default encoding'. Until Java17 or so (somewhere after java11, at any rate), java has been modified - the platform default is always UTF-8. Earlier, it was whatever your system's platform default is. Which on linux is often Utf-8, on windows usually Cp1252, on mac.. I'm guessing UTF_8 too. Point is, you're getting UTF-8 here.
UTF-8 does not work here
You want to convert any byte value to UTF-8 and back. This is impossible - There are sequences of bytes that are invalid UTF-8 and therefore not representable. So, if you have a sequence of bytes that isn't valid UTF-8, and you go through the steps of 'read these bytes as a string by applying UTF-8 as the charset, because a charset always is applied in such conversions, and then convert the resulting string to bytes using UTF-8', the bytes get mangled.
The real fix
There is no reason to ever do this. Just.. don't. Convert the bytes to nibbles (byte 0x05 turns into the string `"05" - the string consists of only 0-9 and A through F), or base64, or something else.
What you're asking for - but should not do
Use a charset encoding that has the property that it can [A] represent each and every one of the 256 bytes as a character that 'survives' back-and-forth conversion, and [B] (Bonus) has a fixed length - each character it can represent will convert to a byte on a 1-to-1 basis (in UTF-8, that's not true; For example, ë takes 2 or 3 bytes).
ISO-8859-1 is guaranteed to be available on any JVM, and has that property. Thus, replace new String(bytes) (never use that constructor, it confuses you, as it has here), with new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), and str.getBytes() with str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).
However, you shouldn't do that. For example, the byte '13' will turn into a newline. The byte '7' will turn into a bell sound. '127' turns into 'delete'. I'm pretty sure JTextArea won't perform the associated control action (so, no bells will sound, and 127 doesn't delete the previous char), because that'd be silly. But these chars don't have a symbol. So it'll be very weird. The byte '0' turns into the NULL character which usually does not survive transitions anywhere else, though it will survive back-and-forth through a JTextArea... probably. Nowhere in the spec of JTextArea does it say that tossing control characters at it is supported, so even if it does work, it might not work on another machine, or another JVM release.

ISO-8859-1 is guaranteed to be available on any JVM, and has that property. The trouble is - it doesn't. For one thing 0x7F thru 0x9F are undefined. There are much better candidates. Of course, those candidates are somewhat subjective and might be 'foreign' to whomever is using this hex editor.

Java's own charset converters can transfer a byte array containing any permutation of all possible values to ISO-8859-1 and back again without loss. Yes, in other systems that's not guaranteed, but, then, if you want guarantees, that's simply not how the internet works. Best bet is to BASE64 it and pray.

Yes, I see what you mean, but I thought the idea was to have some sort of character glyph representation for every possible (where printable) byte

@G00se possibly; I'm wondering if I need to toss a reference to base64 in here. Let's see if OP wants to chime in :)

MacRoman is good iirc - no holes
